# aggregate command in R

Tags: r, aggregate

How can I use aggregate command for converting this table:

```
name  ID   
a     1   
a     2 
a     2
a     NA   
b     NA   
c     NA
c     NA
```

to this one:

```
name  ID   
a     1|2    
b     NA   
c     NA
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base:

```
> aggregate(ID ~ name, data=x, FUN=function(y) paste(unique(y), 
                                      collapse='|'),na.action=na.pass)
  name     ID
1    a 1|2|NA
2    b     NA
3    c     NA
```

This differs from your specification in the handling of the fourth row.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
library(tidyr);
df$name <- as.factor(df$name)

aggregate(ID ~ name, unique(df[complete.cases(df),]), paste, collapse = "|") %>% 
   complete(name)

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

    name    ID
  (fctr) (chr)
1      a   1|2
2      b    NA
3      c    NA
```

The logic here is filtering out all incomplete rows and duplicated rows firstly, paste the ID together and then use the `complete` function from `tidyr` package to automatically fill the factor variable with all the levels to make sure no information is missing.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'name', `if` the elements in 'ID' are `all` NA, then we return the NA or `else` `paste` the `unique` elements that are not NA in the 'ID' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(ID= if(all(is.na(ID))) NA_character_ else 
           paste(na.omit(unique(ID)), collapse = "|")), by = name]
#   name  ID
#1:    a 1|2
#2:    b  NA
#3:    c  NA
```

---

The same methodology can be used in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(name) %>% 
   summarise(ID = if(all(is.na(ID))) NA_character_ 
                   else paste(unique(ID[!is.na(ID)]), collapse="|"))
#   name    ID
#  <chr> <chr>
#1     a   1|2
#2     b  <NA>
#3     c  <NA>
```